# Docker no permission to mounted volume

Tags: linux, docker

I am running a docker with a mounted volume

```
docker run -it --rm --network=host --gpus all -v /data/rsg/nlp/yujieq:/scratch nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:21.04-py3 /bin/bash
```

Although I am the `root` user in the container, I don't have the write permission to the `/scratch` directory. `ls -l` gives

```
total 82
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root  root     7 Apr  1 01:23 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x    2 root  root  4096 Apr 15  2020 boot
drwxr-xr-x    5 root  root   580 May  9 06:41 dev
drwxr-xr-x    1 root  root  4096 May  9 06:41 etc
drwxr-xr-x    2 root  root  4096 Apr 15  2020 home
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root  root     7 Apr  1 01:23 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root  root     9 Apr  1 01:23 lib32 -> usr/lib32
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root  root     9 Apr  1 01:23 lib64 -> usr/lib64
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root  root    10 Apr  1 01:23 libx32 -> usr/libx32
drwxr-xr-x    2 root  root  4096 Apr  1 01:23 media
drwxr-xr-x    2 root  root  4096 Apr  1 01:23 mnt
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  root  4096 Apr 22 22:08 nvidia
drwxr-xr-x    1 root  root  4096 Apr 23 01:49 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 1032 root  root     0 May  9 06:41 proc
drwx------    1 root  root  4096 Apr 23 01:29 root
drwxr-xr-x    1 root  root  4096 May  9 06:41 run
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root  root     8 Apr  1 01:23 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxrwsr-x   18 24193 17131   20 May  9 06:09 scratch
drwxr-xr-x    2 root  root  4096 Apr  1 01:23 srv
dr-xr-xr-x   13 root  root     0 May  8 16:29 sys
drwxrwxrwt    1 root  root  4096 May  9 06:41 tmp
drwxr-xr-x    1 root  root  4096 Apr  1 01:23 usr
drwxr-xr-x    1 root  root  4096 Apr  1 01:26 var
drwxrwxrwx    1 root  root  4096 Apr 23 01:49 workspace
```

I cannot do `chown` or `chmod` to the `/scratch`. How should I get the write permission?

Comment: Can you run `docker run -it --rm --network=host --gpus all -v /data/rsg/nlp/yujieq:/scratch ubuntu /bin/bash` to see if you have the same problem ?

Comment: @Philippe Yes, the same problem

Comment: Is `/data/rsg/nlp/yujieq` on a network drive, or on your local linux box ? Can you try mounting a local directory ? For example `-v $HOME:/scratch`

Comment: It is indeed a network drive. It works with a local directory. Do you have any thoughts on how to mount a network drive?

Comment: You can try `--user $(id -u):$(id -g)`. But then you will not be `root` in the container.

Comment: Thank you! Specifying the user id does give me the access to that folder, but since I am not the root, I cannot `pip install` packages. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: Use python virtual environment.